# Web-service moniker in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, web-services, wcf

I have a **VBA macro** which uses a **moniker** generated by `GetObject` to interact with a **WCF web-service**.

The string describing the web-service passed to `GetObject` looks like:

```
service:mexaddress=http://my.net/ws/MyService.svc/mex,
address=http://my.net/ws/MyService.svc,
contract=IMyService,
contractNamespace=http://tempuri.org/,
binding=BasicHttpBinding_IMyService,
bindingNamespace=http://tempuri.org/
```

All is working fine on ***Windows 7*** with ***Excel 2010***.

But on ***Windows 10*** with ***Excel 2016*** it fails with an **`Automation Error Invalid Syntax 800401e4`**.

I've tried different syntaxes seen on documentation and tutorials like `service4:mexAddress`, with and without quotes `'` and double-quotes `"`... but with no luck so far.

I've even tried to debug it with Visual Studio as I've read that the web-service moniker stuff is implemented in .Net and that I could catch some more explicit exception, but none was caught though I've asked Visual to catch everything it can.

---

**EDIT 1**

- I've built a new basic WCF service from scratch and the result is the same,
- I've traced Excel.exe with ProcMon; not sure it is relevant but on Windows 10/Excel 2016 I see that it tries to access pathes like `C:\Users\my-user\Documents\service:mexaddress=http://my.net/ws/MyService.svc/mex, address=http:` whereas it is not the case on Windows 7/Excel 2010.
  Maybe it's missing the component that handles the `service` "protocol".

---

**EDIT 2**

- I've tried to directly embed the **WSDL metadata** into the connection-string (as described in [Using the WCF Moniker with COM Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/using-the-wcf-moniker-with-com-clients)) but still the same error,
- I've tried to spy the HTTP exchanges with the **Fiddler proxy** but no request are visible.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue? Any updates? I'm having exact same issue and also tried to create a very simple WCF service to use it in VBA. The service works with all kinds of other tools but not with Office.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. So instead of directly using VBA we've leveraged our C# XLL by writing a small proxy in C# (that itself uses the WS through a VS service reference) that we call from VBA. It's working perfectly with this workaround. :-)